# Derivative scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, derivative

The d function should return the derivate of the inputted expression in its simplified form. I understand there is a derivate scheme function but instead I'm using lists to challenge myself. I am new to the language. I've written test cases to test my solution but the expected output is wrong and not simplified.

```
(define d
  (λ (e)
    (cond ((number? e) 0)
      ((equal? e 'x) 1)
      (else
       (let ((op (car e)) (args (cdr e)))
         (apply (lookup op d-op-table) args))))))


(define d-op-table
  (list(list '+   (λ (u v)(list '+ (d u) (d v))))
       (list '-   (λ (u v)(list '- (d u) (d v))))
       (list '*   (λ (u v)(list '+ (list '* u (d v))(list '* v (d u)))))))
       (list 'sin (λ (u)(list '*( list 'cos (d u)))))
       (list 'cos (λ (u)(list '*( list '-sin (d u)))))
       (list 'log (λ (u)(list '* (list '/1 u) (d u))))
       (list 'exp (λ (u)(list '* (d u)(list 'exp u))))
       (list 'expt (λ (u v) (list 'expt (list '* v  u) (- v 1))))

(define lookup
  (λ (op
      table)
    (if (equal? op (caar table))
    (cadar table)
    (lookup op (cdr table)))))



;; Test cases

;; (d '(* (+ x 4) (+ x -7)))
;; '(+ (* (+ x 4) (+ 1 0)) (* (+ x -7) (+ 1 0)))

;; (d '(* x (* x (* x (* x x)))))
;; '(+ (* x (+ (* x (+ (* x (+ (* x 1) (* x 1))) (* (* x x) 1))) (* (* x (* x x)) 1))) (* (* x (* x (* x x))) 1))
```

Example:

By inputting the function

```
(d '(* (+ x 1) (+ x -1)))
```

I expect

```
(+ (* (+ x 1) (+ 1 0)) (* (+ 1 0) (+ x -1)))
```

but i get

```
(+ (* (+ x 1) (+ 1 0)) (* (+ x -1) (+ 1 0)))
```

Comment: You have derivative code, but no simplification code.

Comment: Could you show what you get versus what you expect?

Comment: By inputting the function (d '(* (+ x 1) (+ x -1))) I expect  (+ (* (+ x 1) (+ 1 0)) (* (+ 1 0) (+ x -1))) but i get '(+ (* (+ x 1) (+ 1 0)) (* (+ x -1) (+ 1 0)))

Comment: Put the details in the question.

Comment: You have two extra `)` on the `*` line of `d-op-table`. They should be on the `expt` line.

Comment: The result you're getting is equivalent to what you want, it just has the arguments to `*` in the opposite order. But it's commutative.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the case for multiplication says so here:

```
(list '+ (list '* u (d v)) (list '* v (d u)))
```

That is, `d(u*v) = u * dv + v * du`.

The second term is "flipped" compared to what you say want, which is `d(u*v) = u * dv + du * v`:

```
(list '+ (list '* u (d v)) (list '* (d u) v))
```